# Mocking web services that send IP multicast

Tags: web-services, kubernetes, mocking, udp, multicast

I'm writing a web application that consumes a couple of different web services that each send data over IP multicast. I'm interested in mocking these services so I can test my web application under controlled conditions but I cannot find an existing solution that provides this capability.

I've come across several options for mocking traditional HTTP web services but nothing that supports sending multicast. Does anyone have experience with this or do I have to roll my own solution for now?